# Convergence with even and odd subsequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of real numbers satisfying:
>
> - The subsequence $(a_{2k})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is decreasing;
> - The subsequence $(a_{2k-1})_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is increasing;
> - $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_{n+1}-a_n|=0$.
>
> Prove that $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is convergent.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I know that $\lim |a_{n+1}-a_n|=0$ is not sufficient for $a_n$ to be convergent, but I have no clue how to incorporate the 'increasing and decreasing' subsequences in a proof. I think I need to use the Cauchy criterion, but I don't know how to proceed :(

Comment: Hint:: The sequence $u_k=a_{2k}-a_{2k+1}$ is decreasing and $\to 0$ ; Show that this imply that $u_k\geq 0$ for all $k$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that for two natural numbers $k$ and $l$, $a_{2k}<a_{2l-1}$. Suppose furtermore that $k\leqslant l$. Then $a_{2l}\leqslant a_{2k}<a_{2l-1}$. Therefore, $n\geqslant l\implies a_{2n}\leqslant a_{2l}<a_{2l-1}\leqslant a_{2n-1}$ and so$$n\geqslant l\implies|a_{2n}-a_{2n-1}|=a_{2n-1}-a_{2n}\geqslant|a_{2l}-a_{2l-1}|$$and this contradicts the assumption that says that $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_{n+1}-a_n|=0$. You'll also reach a contradiction of $k\geqslant l$.

So, you always have $a_{2k}\geqslant a_{2l-1}$. Now, take $\varepsilon>0$. If $N$ is large enough, $a_{2N}-a_{2N-1}<\varepsilon$. But then, if $n\geqslant N$, we have $a_{2n}\leqslant a_{2N}$ and $a_{2n}\geqslant a_{2N-1}$. And we also have $a_{2n-1}\leqslant a_{2N}$ and $a_{2n-1}\geqslant a_{2N-1}$. So, after a certain point, *all* terms of the seqeunce belong to an inter whose length is smaller than $\varepsilon$. Therefore, $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is a Cauchy sequence, as you supected.